# joomla virtuemart search slash error

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, virtuemart

i am currently developing one `joomla` site which contains `virtuemart` and my written component which is working quite well, but the problem shows up when i try to search for products using `virtuemart` search in example when i search for `12/4 name` it replaces `12/4 name` with `124 name` and displays no results.

So the question is where is that `sql-query` that loads those items so i can modify it?
or is there another `plug-in` or something that works with `/` or is there somekind of fix to this problem?

Comment: I suspect your using stripslashes somewhere in the result to remove the slashes before html chars. However its removing the extra slashes as well. Try searching for/playing about with that!

Comment: @GeorgeWilson could you please point me out what's being ron on search? My guess is `virtuemart` search `plugin`...... And if yes than its using `joomlas` intagrated command which uses these methods `mysql_real_escape_string` and `addslashes`. I don't know much about `joomla` and `PHP` but could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a while i finnaly fixed this issue. My fix is not weary good beacose i didn't find where exactly `virtuemart` component removes slash from search query so i just did like this......

As `frontend` uses modules who are located at `admin/components/com_virtuemart/modules` i had to edit module named `product`. And in the function named `sortSearchListQuery2` i added some code

```
 if ($useCore) {
//      if ( $this->keyword !== "0" and $group ===false) {
            if (!empty($this->keyword) and $this->keyword !== '' and $group === FALSE) {
                $this->setKeyWord($_GET['keyword']);//Added this line!
                        //$keyword = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', '%', $keyword), '%');
                $keyword = '"%' . $this->_db->getEscaped ($this->keyword, TRUE) . '%"';
                //var_dump($keyword,$this->keyword,$_GET['keyword']); debug_zval_dump($keyword); debug_print_backtrace(); die();
```

And on `frontend` view named `Category` in `view.html.php` i replaced `$keyword=vmRequest::uword('keyword', '', ' ')` with `$keyword = $_GET['keyword']`

And that is my approach to fix this problem!